# Mixing User Data For Cross-Validation

Tags: sampling, predictive-models, cross-validation, validation, population

I have data from 12 users, and want to perform cross-validation. Is it necessary that I create my training and test data from different users, or can all of the data be randomized, and then split into Train and Test?

**EDIT**
This dataset is large, as we are observing user's typing patterns, for multiple typing sessions. We're measuring 100s of features, once per answer per user. Hopefully this helps give a better idea of our data.

Comment: A good question that would be even better if you told more about your data.  E.g., how many variables are measured per user?  Are there repeated measures?  If so, how many observations per variable per user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the test set and the validation sets are supposed to be different.

Second, when you have a small number of data points (users, not features measured from each user), you may want to use [leave-one-out cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#Leave-one-out_cross-validation). This means you would determine which model to use by training each model 12 times, leaving out each user in turn, and you measure the model by how well it predicts the left out data on average.

Third, if you expect that there is some correlation between answers to different questions from the same user, then using the properties of some answers to predict the properties of another answer by the same person is only reasonable if your goal is to predict a user's patterns from past data from the same person. It is not valid if you are trying to predict how other people behave.

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend not leave-one-out but repeated/iterated k-fold cross validation, which allows more than 12 combinations of users into models, and thus a better measure of model stability.

Comment: @DouglasZare, I understand your first two points but I'm not sure I understand the third.  Assume I want to predict outcomes for new users and not just new outcomes for the users in the training data.  Is there an example from the typing session analogy that would help illustrate your third point (especially to show what "correlation between answers to different questions from the same user" means in this case)?  Thanks.

Comment: @dnlbrky: Suppose one user's answers have features A and B. In the population, A is rare, and is not closely correlated to B. If you use that person's data for both the training set and validation set, this will favor a model which can learn that A is correlated with B, which will not be true when you generalize. If you don't use the same person's data for both sets, then if you learn the pattern in the training set, it probably won't be there in the validation set, so the model will (correctly) not score well.